Looking for a movie between 2005 and 2010 about a betrayed FBI agent
Looking for a movie where an FBI agent is betrayed. For some reason (he gets a note that he has to be there for a conversation, but no one shows up) the agent sits in a (I thought Irish or Italian) mob restaurant which the FBI had under investigation.
He escapes from his apartement when the FBI wants to arrest him. The leader of the arrestation team warns his personnel that the betrayed FBI agent knows all the steps they are going to take.
His own colleagues are hunting for him, and one scene is that he dares (I thought his best) friend to shoot at him because he knows he doesn't fire.
The recordings were taken in the USA (I thought LA or NYC).
I don't know any more of the plot. Only that it was a cinema movie.
If I have to make a guess, the movie is released between 2006 and 2010

I think you're looking for The Negotiator (1998)


In a desperate attempt to prove his innocence, a skilled police
  negotiator accused of corruption and murder takes hostages in a
  government office to gain the time he needs to find the truth.

The scene you describe where he challenges his friends to shoot him is very vivid indeed and I am not surprised that this is what you remember clearly. 
During the confrontation he is holding hostages in a skyscraper. He is desperately trying to prove that he was framed and he does not believe his friends will kill him rather than disobey an order.
This scene begins at 1:09 and continues into 1:14 where he leans out of the window daring every other sniper to shoot him.
The movie is indeed a cinema feature and it's a pretty good watch featuring Samuel L. Jackson and Kevin Spacey in their prime.
